# How can I store User data to my User node using AngularFir?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I Have created my login and have been able to allow users to signup now. However I want to store user data to my node. I added the code that I thought should work inside the addUser function. I have worked on this for ages but cannot find a solution. Could someone point me in the right direction as to what I am doing wrong?

The code I have written is below. Thanks in advance.

```
'use strict';

var theBigWeddingBook = angular.module('theBigWeddingBook');

theBigWeddingBook.controller('RegCtrl', function ($scope, $firebaseAuth,   $firebaseObject)

{
  var ref = new Firebase("https://the-big-wedding-book.firebaseio.com");
  var reg = $firebaseAuth(ref);

$scope.user = {};

$scope.addUser = function() {
    var username = $scope.user.email;
    var password = $scope.user.password;
    var uid = $scope.user.uid;

    reg.$createUser({
        email: username,
        password: password
    }).then(function(user) {
        console.log('User has been successfully created!');
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })

    ref.child('user').child(user.uid).set(user).then(function(user) {
        console.log('Data Saved Successfully!');
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
};
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working. I basically change it so that when Someone registers they are automatically logged in and then on authentication the data is saved to the user node as you can see below.

```
var theBigWeddingBook = angular.module('theBigWeddingBook');

theBigWeddingBook.controller('RegCtrl', function ($scope, $firebaseAuth, $firebaseObject) {

    var ref = new Firebase("https://the-big-wedding-book.firebaseio.com");
    var reg = $firebaseAuth(ref);

    ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
      if (authData) {
        console.log("Authenticated with uid:", authData.uid);
      } else {
        console.log("Client unauthenticated.")
      }
    });

    $scope.user = {};

    $scope.addUser = function() {
        var username = $scope.user.email;
        var password = $scope.user.password;
        var uid = $scope.user.uid;

        reg.$createUser({
            email: username,
            password: password
        }).then(function(user) {
            console.log('User has been successfully created!');
            return reg.$authWithPassword({ email: username, password: password });
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
    };

    ref.onAuth(function(authData) {
        ref.child('user').child(authData.uid).set(authData).then(function(auth) {
            console.log('Data Saved Successfully!');
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        })
    })

})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$scope.addUser = function() {

  var uid = $scope.user.uid;

  reg.$createUser({
    email: $scope.user.email,
    password: $scope.user.password
  }).then(function(user) {
     console.log('User has been successfully created!');
  }).catch(function(error) {
    console.log(error);
  })
})
```

OR

```
  $scope.addUser = function() {
    var username = $scope.user.email;
    var password = $scope.user.password;
    var uid = $scope.user.uid;

    reg.$createUser({
        email: this.username,
        password: this.password
    }).bind(this)
      .then(function(user) {
        console.log('User has been successfully created!');
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    })
```

Comment: This doesnt save the UID and Provider to the custom user nodes that I have created in the firebase JSON does it?

Comment: Well that was not captured in your original code that you posted. So I did not do that, but the logic stays the same.